# Como resolver questões relacionadas a carregamento de módulos/classes que ainda continuam na memória?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Volta e meia meu Sidekiq obtém o erro apresentado abaixo, e logo em seguida é jogado novamente para fila de execução. Apos um tempo, automaticamente o erro desaparece e a fila continua a execução normalmente.

```
ArgumentError: A copy of StateMachines::RemittanceStateMachine has been removed from the module tree but is still active!
```

Gostaria de ter um entendimento melhor sobre o problema para que consiga evita-lo no futuro.

Comment: Percebo tambem em alguns casos que o erro é outro, mas por algum motivo o erro acaba escondido e essa mensagem é apresentada ao invés do problema real.

Comment: Veja se é o seu caso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636334/a-copy-of-xxx-has-been-removed-from-the-module-tree-but-is-still-active

Comment: @AlexTakitani sua referencia me ajudou muito, a solução que encontrei foi mudar o diretorio de `app/models/state_machines` para `app/state_machines`. Parece ser um problema de carregamento do autoload na alteração do arquivo.

Comment: Incrível, basta alterar alguma coisa em um arquivo `name_state_machine.rb` que o problema acontece.